# Speed up Pyspark mllib job

Tags: performance, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am running a Pyspark MLLib job on EMR.
The RDD has 98000 rows.
When I am executing Kmeans on it, it takes hours and still shows 0%.
I tried enabling maximizeresourceAllocation and increasing memory of the executors and the driver, but it is still the same.
How can I speed it up?
following is the code I am executing:

```
from numpy import array
from math import sqrt
import time
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
start=time.time()
clusters = KMeans.train(parsedata,88000, maxIterations=5, initializationMode="random")
def error(point):
    center = clusters.centers[clusters.predict(point)]
    return sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in (point - center)]))
WSSSE = parsedata.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
print("Within Set Sum of Squared Error = " + str(WSSSE))
print time.time()-start
```

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're asking it to create 88000 clusters, is it really what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to create those many clusters, plus even if I try a small number it is slow.